# render() fails to convert .Rmd to .pdf in a containerized Shiny app

Tags: r, docker, r-markdown

I'm running a Shiny app in a docker container. The app pulls/handles data from Google Analytics, passes those data into an `.Rmd` file, knits the file into a beamer presentation, then offers that file for download. The docker image is running `R v3.4.4.` with `rmarkdown v1.10`. The app works as it should except for the final step during which I use `render()` to knit the `.Rmd` to a `.pdf`.

`pdflatex` is installed and accessible in my container:

```
root@de4bd1ee457a:/# pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
```

My `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4
```

Shiny server log:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:45211
2018-08-07 13:49:19> No scopes have been set, set them via 
options(googleAuthR.scopes.selected) - 
  no authentication attempted.

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

  filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

  intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

2018-08-07 13:49:20> Default Google Project for googleAnalyticsR is now set.  
This is shared with all googleAnalyticsR users. 
If making a lot of API calls, please: 
  1) create your own Google Project at https://console.developers.google.com 
2) Activate the Google Analytics Reporting API 
3) set options(googleAuthR.client_id) and options(googleAuthR.client_secret) 
4) Reload the package.
2018-08-07 13:49:20> Set API cache
2018-08-07 13:49:20> No environment argument found, looked in GA_AUTH_FILE

Attaching package: ‘jsonlite’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

  validate

2018-08-07 13:49:36> Downloaded [5045] rows from a total of [5045].


processing file: GA_report.Rmd
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
output file: GA_report.knit.md
```

I have verified that the `GA_report.knit.md` is created successfully (along with all figures in the `.Rmd` file). In the container in an `R` session, I can run `render()` on the `...knit.md` file and create the final beamer presentation `.pdf` without issue. It's just that the final step wherein the `*.knit.md` is converted to `.pdf` and is offered for download fails.

When I look in the `dir` that contains my `.Rmd` file, there is no `.tex` file, only the `GA_report.knit.md` and `GA_report.utf8.md`.

The header of my `.Rmd`

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "SwCustom"
title: "`r paste0('Draft report: ', params$client)`"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
toc: FALSE
classoption: aspectratio=169
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
params:
  data: NA
  client: NA
---
```

The `render()` statement

```
render("report/GA_report.Rmd", 
       output_format = "all",
       output_file = file, 
       params = params, 
       envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()), 
       clean = FALSE, 
       quiet = FALSE)
```

My custom beamer theme is accessible in the container

```
root@de4bd1ee457a:/# kpsewhich beamerthemeSwCustom.sty
/opt/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerthemeSwCustom.sty
```

What could be going on here? It seems like all signs should be pointing to yes when it comes to getting the file to completion, but I'm at a loss as to what could be the issue.

Comment: Is pandoc installed in container. knit to pdf requires it in my knowledge, but not sure if that will solve the problem

Comment: `pandoc` is installed. At least, when I look at `pandoc --version`, I'm given `pandoc 1.19.2.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is related to a max timeout error in Shiny Server. My docker container is running Shiny Server and, [this issue on the Shiny Server github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/197) suggests that there is a hard-coded timeout in `downloadHandler()` in Shiny Server. As my `.Rmd` files are rather large, it takes much longer to convert to `.pdf` than the auto timeout. Because `downloadHandler()` never offered what I expected up for download, I would cancel the process and the final `.pdf` was never created.

Refactoring my app to include two buttons, one for generating the report and one for downloading the report, was my solution. This got around the hard-coded timeout for `downloadedHandler()` by allowing the knitting of the `.Rmd` to take place outside of `downloadHandler()`.